# Does text-shadow not render on ios?

Tags: css, shadow

Using light text over an image, text is located in different places based on screen/device. So I added in text-shadow values to help it stand out. Works perfectly on chrome/safari/ff on OSX, but no shadow appearing on iOS?

Previous shadow-related questions for iOS seem to be about UIlabels, not about css text-shadow. Is it well-known not to work on iOS, or any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried -webkit prefix?

Comment: Would look like this? 
-webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px #000; 

to go with existing:
text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;

So have just tried and that doesn't do it.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow

Comment: So @Pete that link is saying text-shadow should def work for iOS 7.1, and has been supported since 3.2? Not my experience at the moment.

Comment: Should text-shadow not have 3 dimensions - Horizontal Length, Vertical Length and Blur Radius? eg `text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #000000;`  Maybe iOS can't parse it when it only has 2

Comment: Hmm, added in blur radius, still not it. Thanks for your time, other suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could be that your mobile browser has cached the stylesheet.